# Django: DetailView, Where to update a counter?

Tags: python, django

I have the following class:

```
class ImageGalleryDetail(DetailView):                                           

    model = ImageGallery                                                        
    template_name = 'galleries/imagegallery_detail.html'                        

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                                       
        context = super(ImageGalleryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)    
        context['image'] = self.object                                          
        context['gallery'] = self.object.owner_gallery                          

        return context                                                          

    def update_counter(self):                                                                                                                        
        self.object.hits = F('hits') + 1                                        
        self.object.save()
```

And as you can see I have a method called `update_counter()` where I used an `F expression` to update a counter atomically.

My question is, where should I locate the call to this function? the way I see it I could locate it in the `get_context_data()` method but it sounds odd to me, the name of the method starts with **get** not **set**. And I think I shouldn't be saving model-related stuff in there... (beginner here!)

[Method Flowchart](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/) of DetailView is the following:

```
1. dispatch()
2. http_method_not_allowed()
3. get_template_names()
4. get_slug_field()
5. get_queryset()
6. get_object()
7. get_context_object_name()
8. get_context_data()
9. get()
10. render_to_response()
```

So I honestly have no idea what method should I overwrite in order to call `update_counter` function. Any help would be appreciated. Or if this is the wrong way of doing things... I would like to know that too! :)

Comment: You'd better define this counter method into the model ImageGallery itself or define a custom manager for it. Just in case to keep the Logic out of View part.

Comment: @sheshkovsky I do share your thoughts about this. Would you like to share just the simplest of examples of how to do this at the model ImageGallery itself? I'll appreciate that and accept it as the answer to my question :-)

Comment: I've wrote my ideas as an answer. But I'm not sure where should you call those methods in your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to keep the logic out of views, you may define new integer field and define your counter finder as the model method.

```
class ImageGallery(models.Model):
    ...
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def update_counter(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1
```

Another way could be adding a new custom manager:

```
class ImageGalleryManager(models.Manager):
    def update_counter(self, pk):
        self.filter(id=pk).update(count=F('count')+1)

class ImageGallery(models.Model):
    ...
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = ImageGalleryManager()
```

Check out [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/) official documentation for more info.

Comment: I like the first method better, the one that is part of `ImageGallery` itself. But then again, where do you call the function `update_counter` from?

Comment: call the method in `get_context_data` and then pass it to the template as part of context dictionary if you need to show the `count` value in your template.

Answer (score 0):

in a detail view  if your model contains a page_click field

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    obj = self.get_object()
    obj.page_click = obj.page_click + 1
    obj.save()
    return context
```